# MySQL server fails to start on Fedora 12

Tags: linux, fedora, mysql

I installed MySQL using `yum install mysql` on Fedora 12. Now how do I start the server?

```
[root@localhost init.d]# which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql

[root@localhost init.d]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.46, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

---

Here's the list of all the above commands I tried

```
[root@localhost init.d]# mysql -h localhost -u username -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql
/mysql.sock' (111)
[1]+  Exit 127                /usr/bin/mysqld_safe


[root@localhost init.d]# /etc/init.d/mysql start
bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory


[root@localhost init.d]# /usr/bin/mysql start
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql
/mysql.sock' (111)


[root@localhost init.d]# services mysqld start
bash: services: command not found


[root@localhost init.d]# chkconfig --level 345 mysql on
error reading information on service mysql: No such file or directory

[root@localhost init.d]# service mysql start
mysql: unrecognized service

[root@localhost init.d]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

Had to also do this.. `yum install mysql-server` (Yikes!)

Now I get this error

```
[root@localhost vineeth]# service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting MySQL:                                            [FAILED]

[root@localhost vineeth]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting MySQL:                                            [FAILED]
```

Comment: It should already be running, shouldn't it? Can you connect using `mysql -h localhost -u username -p`?

Comment: You should ask this on superuser.com

> /etc/init.d/mysql start (i think)

Comment: google, you'll find the answer sooner.

Answer (score 1):

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

or

```
/usr/bin/mysql start
```

Comment: The daemon is `mysqld start` or `mysqld_safe`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
services mysqld start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chkconfig --level 345 mysql on
```

But I'm not really sure whether it starts the daemon, or just sets it to autostart.